# Albania traffic requirements

Tags: road-trips, taxes

Is it required to pay a [vignette (road tax)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignette_(road_tax)) in Albania, just like in Bulgaria and Romania?

Comment: I was there in 2013, at that time only one Motorway from Tirana to Pristina was available. Road condition was really good, with a 6-km long  tunnel. Both side in AL and RKS was free to use. There was road with Motorway sign from Tirana to Durras which was actually not Motorway (no interchange at crossing, but big roundabout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official UK government travel advice says you do for Bulgaria and Romania like you say but doesn't say it for Albania. Their information is pretty up to scratch and very trustworthy.

Albania info page has nothing on road tax:

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/albania/safety-and-security

Where as countries that do require it has it stated:

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/romania/safety-and-security

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/bulgaria/safety-and-security

Answer (score 4):

Currently roads are free, but the government is considering asking tolls for some highways in the future.

What you need is car insurance, beacause the insurance you have in your country is not valid in Albania. Just buy one at the border, minimum is 15 days.